# An error occurred: Policy document should not specify a principal

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am trying to create the policy as per the document in amazon doc. But I am facing this error as "An error occurred: Policy document should not specify a principal"

Doc below:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/import-vm-image.html

Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: There are two different kinds of policies mentioned on the page you referenced.  Which step are you working on, and what does your policy look like?  More clarification is needed.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply.

I am talking the about to create service role (trust-policy.json)

Answer (score 15):

Sorry if I'm jumping too late here, but looks like may be you are trying to create IAM identity-based policy and you cannot use the Principal element in an IAM identity-based policy.

You can learn more from here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_identity-vs-resource.html

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is not the best solution but this worked to export/import  image. After the role was created on command line vmimport,  I manually go to AWS console, search the role vmimport and attach the policy AdministratorAccess